# C segfault with calloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, calloc

These two lines are giving me a segfault and I can't figure it out:

```
int** input;
*input = (int*)calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

That's it. The way I understand this is, request memory equal to 5 ints and return the memory address. store the memory address in the value pointed to by input. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that `input` isn't pointing at anything, so you get random behaviour.  You weren't guaranteed a seg fault; you might have been unlucky and simply trampled over some sensitive data somewhere.  Now, if you've trimmed the context too much, and in fact you have a function such as `void some_func(int **output) { *output = (int *)calloc(5, sizeof(int)); }` would make some sense.  The onus on initializing the pointer is on the calling code: `int *array; some_func(&array);` for example.

Comment: You would have the same problem if you did something as simple as `*input = NULL;`. The segfault doesn't have anything to do with the `calloc` part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never initialize `input` so referencing whatever happens to be there, maybe this is what you want

```
int** input;
input = malloc(sizeof(int*));
*input = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: That was it! Learning pointers is not a forgiving process, thank you!

Comment: I am having trouble imagining *why* you would want to deliberately create a pointer-to-pointer in this situation.

Comment: This is just a part of a bigger program, it has to be able to allocate more memory but continue to be reference by the same variable, so double pointer

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to assign to an address that hasn't been allocated yet.  If you assign the value directly to input then it should work.

```
input = (int *) calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

EDIT: I forgot to update the cast, and I thought some more explanation was in order.

The allocation should have been this:

```
input = calloc(5, sizeof(int *));
```

What this does is allocate an array of 5 integer pointers.  Once you have that, you can allocate arrays of integers to store inside those integer pointers.  (Note: I'm assuming C99 support here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    input[i] = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
}
```

What this does is allocate a 5-by-5 matrix of integers, and it's essentially the same as declaring input as follows:

```
int input[5][5];
```

The difference is that in this declaration, the compiler manages the allocation for you, which may or may not be what you want.  For example, if this code is in a function and you want to return a pointer to the matrix that you've allocated then you'll want to allocate the memory yourself.  If you're only using the data structure within the current function then letting the compiler manage the memory will work fine.

Comment: Especially that you ***must not cast the return value of malloc()***.

Comment: malloc() once returned char*, so it was necessary to cast the return value in order to avoid a warning.  And it was customary to cast the return value of malloc() in many places until fairly recently.  I still haven't broken that habit.  You're correct that casting the return value of malloc() is not necessary as of the c89 standard, however.  I've updated the answer to remove the casts.